# L'adito a(i) dubbi si può solo dare?

Tags: word-usage

Ho sempre sentito dire *(non) dare adito a dubbi*.

Ma va bene usarlo con verbi altri che *dare*?

Ad esempio, la seguente frase è corretta?

> Dovrebbe essere rimasto poco adito a (o per?) dubbi

Grammaticalmente mi sembra corretta (al netto del dubbio espresso nelle parentesi), e il significato letterale di *adito* ([1 qui](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/adito_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)) mi farebbe pensare che è così, ma mi suona comunque un tantino strana. E infatti il signoficato [3 su treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/adito_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/), figurato, usa esplicitamente il verbo *dare*, ***dare adito (a qualcosa)***.

Comment: Ho appena notato che ero finito sulla pagina dei sinonimi e dei contrari. Però l'altra non è che mi chiarisca troppo le idee.